# ssh: exited: Error connecting: No route to host

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, router, dd-wrt

I seem to have a fairly common issue but with uncommon symptoms.

I am SSHed into my router and am trying to access my laptop from it via another SSH tunnel.

Laptop IP: 192.168.1.110
Router IP: 192.168.1.1

My laptop can ping and ssh to my router but my router can ping my laptop yet not ssh into it.

It is not an issue with the ssh server on my laptop since ssh'ing into `localhost` works fine and when I had port forwarding it worked from outside the network as well.

It is probably an issue with the ssh client on the router but not an obvious one since I can ssh to any external (as in outside my network) servers.

Any ideas?

I can some commands if you need more technical information.

My router:

```
root@DD-WRT:~# uname -a
Linux DD-WRT 2.6.24.111 #2937 Sat Apr 9 10:39:27 CEST 2011 mips unknown
```

No firewall is running and iptables are empty.

Comment: Your laptop may be firewalled or your sshd may be only listening on localhost.  On linux you can run lsof -i -a -p <pid of root sshd> to see what interfaces it's on.

Comment: @SmilingDragon First of all, I got no firewall (or atleast none that blocks anything). And as for the output (Assuming I did it right) is `lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sshd    1024 root    3u  IPv4 1806072      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
sshd    1024 root    4u  IPv6 1806074      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)`

Comment: Yep that looks right then (the *:ssh says it's listening to port 22 on all interfaces) Humour me and check your firewall though (iptables --list -n) just to be sure?  Failing that, you might be looking at apparmor or selinux getting in the way, do you have either enabled?

Comment: iptables are empty and I got neither of the two mentioned applications.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Oh what? My clipboard acts weird sometimes... :/ Thank you for pointing it out..

Comment: Start  the ssh server on the laptop as follows: *sudo service ssh stop; /usr/sbin/sshd -dD*. From the router try to connect to the laptop as *ssh -vvv you@laptop*. Pls post both outputs.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae When I do that everything works fine.

Comment: Ok. Now, on the laptop, start your service normally (*sudo service ssh start*), then connect from router with *ssh -vvv you@laptop*). Pls post output.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae It works finely now. So the issue is technically resolved but what exactly was causing it and how can I make sure it does not happen again?

Answer (score 1):

It is very strange that a router throws an error

```
 ssh: exited: Error connecting: No route to host
```

for a device on its LAN side. For this to happen, it is necessary that the client (*i.e.*, the laptop) be disconnected (are you on wifi or on ethernet? Wifi disconnections are so much easier) or that the router interface was being reconfigured.

The most likely case is if the laptop is on wifi, because any kind of interference may have caused your packets to be lost. On ethernet, this would be much more unusual, and the most likely explanation would be hardware failure, like a faulty cable.

Another remote, but not altogether unlikely possibility is [*hairpinning*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning), which produces similar effects, but that's not your case, is it?

Comment: The laptop is in fact in fact on the wifi. But is there a permanent solution for this? Because this is driving me up the wall...

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev I can relate to that. Pls start by running  *mtr 192.168.1.1* on your laptop for some time (half an hour?) and then see what is the fraction of dropped packets, then pls report here.